# CSS click to expand keeps jumping to top of browser

Tags: css, expand

I'm using the following css code to expand the full content on click.

```
<style>   
.expand ul li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
}

.expand ul li div {
    display:none;
}

.expand ul li div:target {
    display:block;
}


</style>


<div class="expand">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#expandall">Click here to expand</a>   
   <div id="expandall">Content Content Content Content</div>
   </li>

   </ul>  
</div>
```

The above code shows full content when click onto the link, but the content also jump to the top of browser instead of just expanding beneath.

The demonstration of the issue is [here](http://zohah.com/temp.html). When you click on the "Expand All" hyperlink, the Expand All immediately jumps to the top of browser.

So i'd like to ask how to fix this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm testing both firefox 43.0.2, google chrome, and IE 11 in windows phone 8.1. Maybe the way i describe is not correct. I see the "Expand All" phrase go to the top. Maybe we see the same phenomena, but the way describing is opposite.

Comment: Wait a minute, I misread your question. You mean the "Expand all" link itself ends up at the top of the window? Yes, that's normal. Not sure how to stop that though; you could add some code to suppress the normal behaviour, but then the `:target` wouldn't work either. Hm.

Comment: The jumping behaviour is quite annoying, so maybe i need to find another method. Thank you, Lister!

Comment: If you're willing to rewrite your page, there are alternatives, yes. I'll type up an answer.

Comment: I intentionally added rubbished content to the page to show how it jumps. If i removes it, the page will look clean and neat, and fit well into one page of browser, so no jumping behavior is observed. Or, how do you want me to rewrite the page? Please give me some more details. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show or hide blocks of text, an alternative method to using an `<a>` and `:target` is a hidden checkbox and `:selected`.
This way, you don't have the jump and the changed url.

```css
.expand {
  display: none;
}
label[for='expandall'] {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.collapsed {
  display: none;
}
#expandall:checked ~ .collapsed {
  display: block;
}
/* optional: add note when expanded */
#expandall:checked ~ label[for='expandall']::after {
  content:' (click again to collapse)';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="expandall" class="expand"/>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<label for="expandall">Expand all</label>
<p class="collapsed">This is the block that is normally invisible, but will be shown after a click on Expand All. This is the block that is normally invisible, but will be shown after a click on Expand All. This is the block that is normally invisible, but will be shown after a click on Expand All.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the HTML5 `summary` and `details` tags.  [w3schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp).

```html
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
  <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
</details>
```

Comment: This one doesn't work in all browsers yet. Check carefully if the result is acceptable everywhere!